# Remove all elements from a linked list of integers that have value val. My code is wrong, I don'nt know why

Tags: java, queue

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {

    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        Queue<ListNode> my = new LinkedList<>();
        if(head == null)
            return head;
        while(head != null)
        {
            if(head.val == val){}
            else
                my.add(head);
            head = head.next;
        }
        if(my.size() == 0)
            return null;

        ListNode newHead = my.remove();
        ListNode temp = newHead;
        while(my.size() != 0)
        {
            temp.next = my.remove();
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return newHead;
    }
}
```

Comment: `My code is wrong` - compile error? runtime error? doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: runtime error. When the input is 1->2->6->3->4->5->6->null, 6,and then my code output 1->2->3->4->5->6->null, isn't 1->2->3->4->5->null. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't list your exact errors I did notice one thing:

After adding all "non-val" nodes to your new LinkedList you did not set the last entered node's next to null. This implies that the last node entered into "my" will still be linked to all the remaining nodes. This will be a problem if your inputed LinkedList ends in "val."

For example, if a list {1,2,3,4,5,5,5} was inputed and the val to be removed was "5", the last three fives would still be in your returned LinkedList as the "4" node still references "5" as the next node and so on. Try the following:

```
 while(my.size() != 0)
    {
        temp.next = my.remove();
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = null; // try adding this******
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for you that you might find useful:

1. Learn to use an interactive debugger. I suspect that you would find your fault fairly quickly by stepping through the code and examining variables.
2. Learn to write unit test cases, getting simple cases working first and then writing more complex ones. Again I suspect you would have avoided this bug.
3. Look for ways of keeping your code clean and simple. There are lots of examples in your code that make it difficult to read (e.g. naming a variable 'my' or having an empty block as the then clause of an `if` statement).
4. You are using a built in collection `LinkedList` to implement your own linked list. That doesn't make a lot of sense. If you are doing this as homework or as an exercise you will likely need to not rely on a collection. Fortunately it's not necessary.

Your bug is in the code:

```
while(my.size() != 0) {
    temp.next = my.remove();
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Once you have removed the final node from `my` and assigned it to `temp`, the size of `my` is now 0 and the `while` loop is not repeated. You never set `next` of the final node to `null` so it is still pointing to whatever it was originally pointing to - which could well be a node with the value you are trying to delete.

You could fix this by adding `temp.next = null;` after the loop. Rather than just fixing that bug I suggest you restructure your code to avoid the use of an intermediate collection.